# Use RazorEngine in .NET 4.6.1 class library (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, razorengine

I want to use the RazorEngine in a .NET Core class library based on .NET 4.6.1. I include the library in my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9.5",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "RazorEngine": "4.4.3-rc1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  }
}
```

When I try to use the RazorEngine in my code, I get the following runtime error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=4.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies.

I think I have to include a further dependency, but which one? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're missing  System.Threading.Thread (>= 4.3.0)  which is a dependency of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor ? [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor/)

Comment: I included the `"System.Threading.Thread": "4.3.0"` after the `"RazorEngine": "4.4.3-rc1"` but the problem remains.

Comment: Which SDK version you are using in global.json?

Comment: @Sanket what do you mean with SDK version? The project.json above is complete. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @BSolutions when you create .net core project from Visual Studio, it also creates global.json at root folder. There you can verify SDK version you are using. I tried to use your project in my .net core class library and it worked without any problem.

Comment: @Sanket The error occurs only when calling a RazorEngine method like `Engine.Razor.RunCompile(...)`. Do you tested that also?